# app do not see classes of module on build

Tags: android, gradle

I have project with app and some module m1 (android library).

I create folders `src\debug\java` in app and m1. I wrote new classes in this folders. Some "debug" classes of app use "debug" classes of m1.

Try build. Get error: `package ... does not exist`. If I click on error, AS do not show any errors, I can go to the classes of m1.

But why it occurred and how it fix?

I'm use AS 2.1 and gradle 2.14 (try 2.10 have no success to).
Try build from AS and cmd.

**UPD 2016-08-13**: Oh, I'm stupid. I forgot remove some code from `main`.

**UPD 2016-08-13(2)**: No, problem in another. Write a post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about very important thing: "**Building Library Projects...When the Library Project is built and packaged into a distribution blob, then the build is always a release build.**" (from [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts)).

I have several projects and one common library, that used in all projects. I create own classes/resources (diagnostic utils, dialogs, preferences, settings) for debug. I place it to common library only for debug build.

I thought: debug classes of library used only in debug classes of app. Release apk will not have this classes.

But I get error on build. Because gradle searching my library classes in release folder on build.

So, I find only one solution:

1) place debug code of library from debug folder back to main folder.

2) Add proguard rules to exclude debug resources of library on release build.